# Get current short branch name in Git using Gradle function

Tags: git, gradle, git-branch

I have a git branch `refs/head/feature/new-function` and would like to extract the short branch name (`new-function`) using git command.

In my **build.gradle**, I have a function to get branch name like:

```
def getVersionFromTag() {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'symbolic-ref', '--short', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

I have tried these two commands but they give me `feature/new-function` instead (I want to remove `feature` word as well):

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

I also know that I can use `cut` to truncate the result with delimiter `\` but the thing is gradle function will treat this slash as unexpected character.

Is there any shorter and robust way to do this?